# Add Blog Entry missing from all users except Host in DNN

Tags: blogs, dotnetnuke

We need for our clients to be able to add an entry to their blog which is being used for their news feeds but the Add Blog Entry option is not available to registered users, only to the Host account. How would I go about setting the blog up so that the users can add a blog entry as well?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page where you have the module installed, go into the module's settings and near the top, you should see a section called Permissions. In there, you'll want to give Registered Users (or another role) edit permissions (and/or perhaps other permissions).